# Continuous transitions (morphing) on Android

Tags: android, animation, transition, morphing

I read a lot about Animations, Scenes and Transitions on Android, but one thing I found mentioned nowhere is what I'll call continuous Transitions. E.g. having the user move a slider from left to right results in "morphing" from one view to the other, so shared elements will move to the new position or fade out if they are not present in the new layout. Using Scenes and a TransitionManager allows me to do sth like that on a button click, but not to interact with the ongoing Transition, so the user can control the speed and direction of the animation. Is this somehow possible in Android? Can I use built in techniques for that or do I have to calculate and map all the translations by hand?

Comment: in theory you could call `Transition#setDuration` for some long time (an hour or so) and use `Transition#setInterpolator` with a custom interpolator but i think it is a nasty workaround

Comment: and unfortunately that approach causes many redundant re-draws of the current scene

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that sounds too hacky to me.

Comment: it is not hacky, its is a workaround, it does use std `Transition` used by a `TransitionManager` with only one change: the transition is not well defined in time but instead it is spread in some undefined period of time